# appending data using NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c

Right now I'm appending data using NSMutableData's -appendBytes:length: like this:

```
int length = [self.trackData length]+3;
[contents appendBytes:&length length:4];
```

Suppose length is 20. In hex, the bytes appended are 16 00 00 00, extended to 4 bytes.
How can I add the additional zeros to the left like in 00 00 00 16?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to swap the bytes to big-endian:

```
int length = NSSwapHostIntToBig([self.trackData length]+3);
[contents appendBytes:&length length:4];
```